# Changing diagonal values if equal to 1

Tags: matlab

I want to change the diagonal values if equal to 1.
is it possible to look for diagonals and change the values in this particular diagonal to another value.

For example:

```
X =

     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1
```

I want to change this diagonal :

```
    1
    0
    1
```

to

```
    2.2
    0
    2.2
```

I tried:

```
XX(logical(eye(size(XX)))) = 2
```

but this will change all the values not only ones.

Could you please explain how to do that for other diagonals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) is useful to manipulate diagonals. It only extracts a diagonal from a matrix, or forms a new matrix given a vector of diagonal elements. But with appropriate arithmetic this is sufficient:

```matlab
X = [1 1 1 0
     1 1 0 1
     1 0 1 1
     0 1 1 1];

k = 2;         % which diagonal to change
d = diag(X,k); % the old diagonal
n = d;
n(n==1) = 2.2; % the new diagonal values
X = X - diag(d,k) + diag(n,k); % subtract old values from diagonal, add new ones
```

Output:

```
X =

   1.00000   1.00000   2.20000   0.00000
   1.00000   1.00000   0.00000   2.20000
   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000
   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000
```

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a solution only using linear indexing. I wanted to avoid generating additional matrices. Nothing's wrong with [Cris Luengo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269366/11089932), that was just for fun.

```matlab
% Input.
X = [1 1 1 0
     1 1 0 1
     1 0 1 1
     0 1 1 1]

% Which diagonal to change.
k = 2;

% Determine dimension.
dim = size(X, 1);

% Calculate indices of diagonal elements.
idx = (max(abs(k), k * dim) + 1):(dim + 1):numel(X);
idx = idx(1:end+min(k+1, 0));

% Replace diagonal elements with new value.
X(idx(X(idx) == 1)) = 2.2
```

Output:

```matlab
X =

   1.00000   1.00000   2.20000   0.00000
   1.00000   1.00000   0.00000   2.20000
   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000
   0.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000
```

Comment: Nice: `max(abs(k), k * dim)`. That was the bit that I didn't want to spend the time to figure out, and decided to go with `diag` instead. :)